# Passing config to angular library that uses HTTPInterceptor

Tags: angular

I'm trying to pass configuration from a UI to a library that will handle some authentications tasks.  The library has an HTTPInterceptor & the UI can work with the library.

I want to now add some config data that will be sent in by the library user.  The config items will be known at compile time.  The code below is my initial attempt, which was based on other SO posts I read.  Both the library & UI build with the syntax below, but the config is not passed into AuthInterceptorService & it looks like the HTTPInterceptor is broken.

I suspect the issue is with the syntax in the "library - auth.module" code snippet.  What is the syntax for providing both an HTTPInterceptor AND config passed in from the UI to AuthInterceptorService ?

**Update**  - more info on the issues im seeinbg

1. The constructor in AuthInterceptorService  logs "config is undefined".
2. I get this exception now then the http interceptor is called - , "ERROR TypeError: this.interceptor.intercept is not a function"

Again , my suspicion is that the library auth.module is not correct, but I can't find any example or documentation showing how to set up both an HTTPInterceptor & allow for config being passed in.  Note, the HTTPInterceptor was working before I added the code to config to be passed in

```
//ui - app.module - uses library
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AuthModule.forRoot({
      refreshPath:'/refresh'
  })
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}



//library - auth.module
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AuthComponent
  ],
  imports: [HttpClientModule],
  exports: [
    AuthComponent,
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: setAuthId,
      multi: true,
      deps: [RefreshService, StorageService, HttpClient]
    },
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: commonAppInitializers,
      multi: true,
      deps: [RefreshService, StorageService, HttpClient]
    },
    {provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AuthInterceptorService, multi: true, deps: [StorageService, HttpClient]},
    {provide: StorageService}
  ]
})
export class AuthComponent{
  public static forRoot(config: Config): ModuleWithProviders<AuthComponent> {
    return {
      ngModule: AuthComponent,
      providers: [
        {
          provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
          useClass: AuthInterceptorService,
          multi: true,
          useValue: config
        }
      ]
    };
  }

//library Config
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';
export interface Config {
  refreshPath: string;
}
export const AuthConfigService = new InjectionToken<Config>('Config');

//library interceptor
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private storageService: StorageService, private httpClient: HttpClient,@Inject(AuthConfigService) private    config: Config) {
    console.log('config is ' + config);
   }


 intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<any> {
    //interceptor code, needs config value
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the error, or output, and how is it different from your desired outcome?

Comment: check out the extra comments under "update".  The config object is not being passed into AuthInterceptorService  and the HTTPInterceptor is broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your close, you need to register the DI Token in the providers array, so that Angular can pass it to your interceptor when it is constructed.

```
//library - auth.module
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AuthComponent
  ],
  imports: [HttpClientModule],
  exports: [
    AuthComponent,
  ],
})
export class AuthComponent{
  public static forRoot(config: Config): ModuleWithProviders<AuthComponent> {
    return {
      ngModule: AuthComponent,
      providers: [
        {
            provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
            useFactory: setAuthId,
            multi: true,
            deps: [RefreshService, StorageService, HttpClient]
        },
        {
            provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
            useFactory: commonAppInitializers,
            multi: true,
            deps: [RefreshService, StorageService, HttpClient]
        },
        {provide: StorageService},
        {
          provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
          useClass: AuthInterceptorService,
          multi: true,
        },
        {
          provide: AuthConfigService,
          useValue: config //<=== Register the config token for dependency injection
        }
      ]
    };
  }
```

Comment: Whoa, that worked!!.  thanks.   I was confused because both the @NgModule block & export class  both can have providers.  What is the best practice for where you should add providers?  IF you need an export class then all providers go there?

Comment: @MrSmith glad it worked. I agree that it's not really clear where to put it, I just put all providers in the forRoot, but some testing showed me that some in providers and some in the forRoot providers array also works fine. If users don't use forRoot the providers won't be registered, so I guess that's something to take into consideration.